# Where to locate "sockets"

Tags: directory-structure, socket

I am new to this, so sorry if its obvious. I am running a Debian server and installing the likes of UWSGI, NGinx etc on there. The configurations keep talking about pointing to "sockets".

In the build options I seem to be able to specify where the sockets for each program go. By default it looks like most of them go in /tmp (not all of them).

Is this a good place for them to go? I'm trying to keep things as organized as possible but just bunging them in `/tmp` doesn't seem like the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a `mkdir /var/run/nginx` (or whatever the program name is) and locate them there.  You can then restrict access to the sockets if needed by changing ownership of the that directory.

It's probably not terribly needed for security reasons unless you are a bit paranoid or let people you don't know very well log in via `ssh`.

Comment: -1 for `It's probably not terribly needed for security reasons`. This is terrible security advice.

Comment: Kindly elaborate.

Comment: Trusting that everyone who has access to your machine is trust-worthy is complete folly. You should only grant access that is expressly needed..